# Programmatically change Drupal profile picture

Tags: php, ajax, forms, drupal, drupal-7

I want to programmatically change my profile picture on a Drupal website, but it change the picture only in one place, so it have the good image but we continue to see the old one each time we display it. What do I need to change please?

Here is my code :

```
<?php
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
chdir($path."/");
define('DRUPAL_ROOT', getcwd()); //the most important line
require_once './includes/bootstrap.inc';
$base_url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);

global $user;
$actual_user = user_load($user->uid);
$uri = $actual_user->picture->uri;

$valid_file = true;

if($_FILES['photo']['name'])
{
    //if no errors...
    if(!$_FILES['photo']['error'])
    {
        //now is the time to modify the future file name and validate the file
        $new_file_name = strtolower($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name']); //rename file
        if($_FILES['photo']['size'] > (1024000)) //can't be larger than 1 MB
        {
            $valid_file = false;
            $message = 'Oops!  Your file\'s size is to large.';
        }

        //if the file has passed the test
        if($valid_file)
        {
            //move it to where we want it to be
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], $uri);
            $message = 'Congratulations!  Your file was accepted.';
        }
    }else{
    //if there is an error...
        //set that to be the returned message
        $message = 'Ooops!  Your upload triggered the following error:  '.$_FILES['photo']['error'];
    }
}

$file = (object) array(
    'uid' => 1,
    'uri' => $uri,
    'filemime' => file_get_mimetype($uri),
    'status' => 1,
  );

$file = file_copy($file, 'public://pictures');

$edit['field_profile_picture'] = $file;
user_save($actual_user, $edit);

echo $message;

?>
```

it get the picture from this form :

```
<form id="edit-profile-image" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Your Photo: <input type="file" name="photo" size="25" />
    <input class="edit-profile-image-submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

With this ajax :

```
$("body").on('click','.edit-profile-image-submit',function(){

    var formData = new FormData($('#edit-profile-image')[0]);
    $.ajax({
        url: '/sites/all/themes/CEX/functions/edit-profile-image.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        async: false,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data)
        },
    });

    return false;
});
```

I hope I forgot nothing, if someone can help me I'm stuck on it...
thank you

Comment: By _edit the picture_ do you mean change it in some way? I dont see any code that is doing anything to the picture?

Comment: yeah sorry, I want to change the picture by the one I have in my form, I made an edit as it was unclear, sorry

Comment: So you mean you want to replace the existing picture with the new picture the user has just supplied in this form?

Comment: That's exactly what I want to do, but the picture change in only one place, and it still show the old one in the admin interface and on display style

Comment: Then quite simply you are not copying the new picture to wherever the web pages are getting the picture from

Comment: It get my images from thumbnails, Drupal don't reload them using the original one ?

Comment: When I go to the admin view, my profile picture is the new one, but it still display the old one everywhere else, that's why I don't get it.